# Printing out results from google map search

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-geocoder

I need to use Google Maps (v3) to check whether an address typed into a search field actually exists and print it out on the screen. That's easy enough to do just by checking whether a latitude/longitude pair is found for that address. However, I have a problem.

When a user types in a broad search, such as a common street name like First Street, I need to print out all the results found so the user can choose one. I do not need to display the results on the map at this point, just show a list of them on the page. I found some code online that is supposed to do just that and I modified it but it doesn't work. I get a 'GClientGeocoder() is not defined' error, but I suspect that even when I get past that the code will have problems so I was wondering if someone with more experience could point me in the right direction.

Here's the code, I hardcoded the search term 'First Street' into the function for testing purposes.

```
function showAddress() {
    var geo;
    geo = new GClientGeocoder();
    var search = 'First Street';
    // ====== Perform the Geocoding ======        
    geo.getLocations(search, function (result)
      {
        //map.clearOverlays(); 
        if (result.Status.code == G_GEO_SUCCESS) {
          // ===== If there was more than one result, "ask did you mean" on them all =====
          if (result.Placemark.length > 1) { 
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Did you mean:";
            // Loop through the results
            for (var i=0; i<result.Placemark.length; i++) {
              document.getElementById("message").innerHTML += "<br>"+(i+1)+": "+result.Placemark[i].address;
            }
          }
          // ===== If there was a single marker =====
          else {
            document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Result found:"+result.Placemark[0].address;
          }
        }
        // ====== Decode the error status ======
        else {
          alert('No results found');
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

"Message" is just a regular `<div>`. The function is called from the body tag:

```
<body onLoad='showAddress()'>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is created for the outdated V2-API, I guess you are loading the V3-API-scripts.

When I run it with the V2-API it works fine.

V2 and V3 are not compatible in any way.

Code translated to V3:

```
    function showAddress() {
      var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder();

      var address = 'First Street';
      geo.geocode({"address": address},
                      function(result,status)
                      {
                        var out='no results found';
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) 
                        {
                          if(result.length==1)
                          {
                            out = "Result found:"+result[0].formatted_address;
                          }
                          else
                          {
                            out = "Did you mean:";
                            for(var i=0;i<result.length;++i)
                            {
                              out+="<br>"+(i+1)+": "+result[i].formatted_address;
                            }
                          }

                        }

                        document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = out;
                      }
                    );
  }
```

[**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xUHAR/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xUHAR/)

Comment: Thanks, can you tell me what I need to change to update it to v3? I figured out that GClientGeocoder should become google.maps.geocoder but now I'm getting an error saying that getLocations() is not a function.

Comment: @Jovan: You'll need to change everything, everything is different in V3, objects, methods, results. See above